# Escribir documentacion de una libreria en un txt

Tags: python

La idea basicamente es pasar toda la documentación a un txt

```
import socket

archivo=('sockets.txt','w')

archivo.write(help(socket))

archivo.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se que razón tienes para hacer esto, si por una casualidad quisieras tener la documentación al completo de Python de forma offline, la puedes [descargar desde la web oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/download.html).La tienes en EPUB, PDF, 
HTML y texto plano.

Dicho esto, puedes hacer lo que quieres usando [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) para generar la documentación y obtener una cadena. Solo tienes que guardar esa cadena en el txt:

```
import pydoc

biblioteca = 'socket'

str_doc = pydoc.render_doc(biblioteca, renderer=pydoc.plaintext)

with open(biblioteca+'.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str_doc)
```

Esto nos crea un bonito txt que empieza así:

> ```
> Python Library Documentation: module socket
>
> NAME
>     socket
>
> DESCRIPTION
>     This module provides socket operations and some related functions.
>     On Unix, it supports IP (Internet Protocol) and Unix domain sockets.
>     On other systems, it only supports IP. Functions specific for a
>     socket are available as methods of the socket object.
>
>     Functions:
>
>     socket() -- create a new socket object
>     socketpair() -- create a pair of new socket objects [*]
>     fromfd() -- create a socket object from an open file descriptor [*]
>     ...
> ```

El código es válido para Python 3.x, aunque se puede seguir la misma idea para Python 2.x (solo hay que modificar el tema del argumento `rendered`).